# jackd and SuperCollider headless problem

Tags: boot, audio, jack, headless

I am trying to boot an RPi autonomously to start jackd, SuperCollider and then play a SuperCollider patch. Jack launches and Supercomputer starts to compile but then something goes wrong.

The script that has been written to do this works when called from the command line having ssh'd into the RPi. However when called autonomously, from crontab, it fails having launched jackd and compiled SuperCollider. This is the readout from the log:

```
jackdmp 1.9.9
Copyright 2001-2005 Paul Davis and others.
Copyright 2004-2012 Grame.
jackdmp comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY
This is free software, and you are welcome to redistribute it
under certain conditions; see the file COPYING for details
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
control device hw:0
control device hw:0
audio_reservation_init
Acquire audio card Audio0
creating alsa driver ... hw:0,0|hw:0,0|1024|3|44100|0|0|nomon|swmeter|soft-mode|32bit
control device hw:0
configuring for 44100Hz, period = 1024 frames (23.2 ms), buffer = 3 periods
ALSA: final selected sample format for capture: 16bit little-endian
ALSA: use 3 periods for capture
ALSA: final selected sample format for playback: 16bit little-endian
ALSA: use 3 periods for playback
```

so that is jackd successfully launched, then to SC:

```
init_OSC
compiling class library..
    NumPrimitives = 532
    compiling dir: '/usr/share/SuperCollider/SCClassLibrary'
    compiling dir: '/usr/share/SuperCollider/Extensions'
    pass 1 done
numentries = 866044 / 10709966 = 0.081
    4573 method selectors, 2342 classes
    method table size 6361664 bytes, big table size 42839864
    Number of Symbols 11135
    Byte Code Size 349373
    compiled 362 files in 14.78 seconds
compile done
sh: 1: svn: not found
Help tree read from cache in 0.17554807662964 seconds
LID: event loop started
Class tree inited in 0.31 seconds
WARNING:
GUI.fromID : The GUI scheme 'swing' is not installed
The current scheme is still 'nil'!
Welcome to SuperCollider, for help type ctrl-c ctrl-h (Emacs) or    :SChelp (vim) or ctrl-U (sced/gedit)
/quit sent

quit done

LID: event loop stopped
```

After the line

```
Welcome to SuperCollider, for help type ctrl-c ctrl-h (Emacs) or    :SChelp (vim) or ctrl-U (sced/gedit)
```

the log from the successful boot via the command line reads:

```
JackDriver: client name is 'SuperCollider'
SC_AudioDriver: sample rate = 44100.000000, driver's block size = 1024
Unknown source port in attempted (dis)connection src_name     [system:capture_2] dst_name [Sup$
JackDriver: connected  system:capture_1 to SuperCollider:in_1
JackDriver: couldn't connect  system:capture_2 to SuperCollider:in_2
JackDriver: connected  SuperCollider:out_1 to system:playback_1
JackDriver: connected  SuperCollider:out_2 to system:playback_2
SuperCollider 3 server ready..
JackDriver: max output latency 69.7 ms
notification is on
```

I'm not sure what is happening here or why ?

Comment: `GUI.fromID : The GUI scheme 'swing' is not installed` -> Is SuperCollider normally a GUI app?  You can't easily start one of those from boot and usually it would be for making a "kiosk".  You could have it start after you log into the GUI.

Comment: @goldilocks SuperCollider can be run from the command line. The line you refer to is spurious and documentation about running SC on an RPi tells one to ignore it ! That is not the issue. I think it's something to do with OSC, or jack deciding to release the audio card. The whole point of my exercise is to have no screen, hence headless . . . I want to just plug the RPi into the mains and have it startup and go . .